# New to JS, why doesn't this deferred script execute?

Tags: javascript

Honestly have no idea why this does not work. I'm reading Professional JavaScript for Web Developers 3rd edition and trying examples. Shouldn't the scripts load right after the html tag is done with?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Example HTML Page</title>
 <script type="test/javascript" defer src="js/example1.js"></script>
 <script type="test/javascript" defer src="js/example2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 alert("test");
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1> test </h2>
 </body>
</html>
```

js/example1.js

```
alert("test");
```

js/example2.js

```
alert("test2");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mistyped "text/javascript" as "test/javascript" in your `<script` tags.

Comment: As OP is writing HTML5, `script` tags' `type` attribute is unnecessary as well.